# Remove Item from QGridLayout

Tags: qt, pyqt

How can i remove an Item **(QSpacerItem)** from a Layout? I am defining my QSpacerItem as follows:

```
    spacerItem =  QSpacerItem(20,80,QSizePolicy.Minimum,QSizePolicy.Expanding)

    n = self.grid.rowCount() + 1
    self.grid.addItem(spacerItem, n, 1)
    self.grid.setRowStretch(n, 100)
```

I want the **spacerItem** to be always the last Element in my Layout, so when i add a new Widget, i want to remove the **spacerItem**, add the new Widget and then append the spacerItem to the End.

Comment: [removeItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#removeItem).

Comment: adding "self.grid.removeItem(spacerItem) doesn't do anything, or am i missing something

Comment: For me, it removes the item from the layout. Which is to say, `grid.count()` increases by one when I add the spacer, and decreases by one when I remove it. If you are getting different behaviour, I suggest you provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem(s) you are having.

Comment: @ekhumoro: the spaceritem is removed. But the row, which was added with the spacerItem, is still existing with the rowStretch of 100. So only add "self.grid.setRowStretch(self.grid.rowCount() - 1,0)" and don't add spacerItem to a new row every time.

Comment: But i want the spacer-Item to be the one which gets scaled, otherwise when i resize the window, my element will be floating down while others are still at the top. Thats why i want the spacer-item to be the last element always

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
all_widgets = self.grid.count() #Count All widgets of grid layout
select_spacer = self.grid.takeAt(all_widgets-1) #Because the index starts at 0
self.grid.removeItem(select_spacer) #
```

Since I can't use deleteLater() to remove the SpacerItem, I use takeAt() to get the element out of the layout even though it doesn't completely remove it, and RemoveItem() does the same thing. I think applying both methods will make the removal more thorough although not completely

Hope it helps you, I just found out but still want to find a better way (via Gtranslate)

Comment: OMG, you can use
'self.grid.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)'
to set default layout align widget to top. I'm sure this is the best possible solution